# Storing Multi-dimensional Lists?

Tags: python, arrays, json

(Code below)

I'm scraping a website and the data I'm getting back is in 2 multi-dimensional arrays. I'm wanting everything to be in a JSON format because I want to save this and load it in again later when I add "tags".

So, less vague. I'm writing a program which takes in data like what characters you have and what missions are requiring you to do (you can complete multiple at once if the attributes align), and then checks that against a list of attributes that each character fulfills and returns a sorted list of the best characters for the context.

Right now I'm only scraping character data but I've already "got" the attribute data per character - the problem there was that it wasn't sorted by name so it was just a randomly repeating list that I needed to be able to look up. I still haven't quite figured out how to do that one.

Right now I have 2 arrays, 1 for the headers of the table and one for the rows of the table. The rows contain the "Answers" for the Header's "Questions" / "Titles" ; ie Maximum Level, 50
This is true for everything but the first entry which is the Name, Pronunciation (and I just want to store the name of course).

So:

```
Iterations = 0
While loop based on RowArray length / 9 (While Iterations <= that)
HeaderArray[0] gives me the name
RowArray[Iterations + 1] gives me data type 2
RowArray[Iterations + 2] gives me data type 3
Repeat until Array[Iterations + 8]
Iterations +=9
```

So I'm going through and appending these to separate lists - single arrays like CharName[] and CharMaxLevel[] and so on.

But I'm actually not sure if that's going to make this easier or not? Because my end goal here is to send "CharacterName" and get stuff back based on that AND be able to send in "DesiredTraits" and get "CharacterNames who fit that trait" back. Which means I also need to figure out how to store that category data semi-efficiently. There's over 80 possible categories and most only fit into about 10. I don't know how I'm going to store or load that data.

I'm assuming JSON is the best way? And I'm trying to keep it all in one file for performance and code readability reasons - don't want a file for each character.

CODE: (Forgive me, I've never scraped anything before + I'm actually somewhat new to Python - just got it 4? days ago)

https://pastebin.com/yh3Z535h

^ In the event anyone wants to run this and this somehow makes it easier to grab the raw code (:

```
import time
import requests, bs4, re
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import json
import os

target_dir = r"D:\00Coding\Js\WebScraper" #Yes, I do know that storing this in my Javascript folder is filthy
fullname = os.path.join(target_dir,'TsumData.txt')

StartURL = 'http://disneytsumtsum.wikia.com/wiki/Skill_Upgrade_Chart'
URLPrefix = 'http://disneytsumtsum.wikia.com'

def make_soup(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    return soup

def get_links(url):
    soup = make_soup(url)
    a_tags = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r"^/wiki/"))
    links = [urljoin(URLPrefix, a['href'])for a in a_tags]  # convert relative url to absolute url
    return links

def get_tds(link):


    soup = make_soup(link)
    #tds = soup.find_all('li',  class_="category normal") #This will give me the attributes / tags of each character
    tds = soup.find_all('table',  class_="wikia-infobox")
    RowArray = []
    HeaderArray = []

    if tds: 
        for td in tds:
            #print(td.text.strip()) #This is everything

            rows = td.findChildren('tr')#[0]
            headers = td.findChildren('th')#[0]


        for row in rows:
            cells = row.findChildren('td')
            for cell in cells:
                cell_content = cell.getText()
                clean_content = re.sub( '\s+', ' ', cell_content).strip()
                if clean_content:
                    RowArray.append(clean_content)


        for row in rows:
            cells = row.findChildren('th')
            for cell in cells:
                cell_content = cell.getText()
                clean_content = re.sub( '\s+', ' ', cell_content).strip()
                if clean_content:
                    HeaderArray.append(clean_content)

        print(HeaderArray)
        print(RowArray)
    return(RowArray, HeaderArray)

    #Output = json.dumps([dict(zip(RowArray, row_2)) for row_2 in HeaderArray], indent=1)
    #print(json.dumps([dict(zip(RowArray, row_2)) for row_2 in HeaderArray], indent=1))
    #TempFile = open(fullname, 'w') #Read only, Write Only, Append 
    #TempFile.write("EHLLO")
    #TempFile.close()


            #print(td.tbody.Series)
            #print(td.tbody[Series])
            #print(td.tbody["Series"])
            #print(td.data-name)
            #time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = get_links(StartURL)
    MainHeaderArray = []
    MainRowArray = []
    MaxIterations = 60
    Iterations = 0
    for link in links: #Specifically I'll need to return and append the arrays here because they're being cleared repeatedly.
        #print("Getting tds calling")
        if Iterations > 38: #There are this many webpages it'll first look at that don't have the data I need
            TempRA, TempHA = get_tds(link)
            MainHeaderArray.append(TempHA)
            MainRowArray.append(TempRA)
        MaxIterations -= 1
        Iterations += 1
        #print(MaxIterations)
        if MaxIterations <= 0: #I don't want to scrape the entire website for a prototype
            break

    #print("This is the end ??")
    #time.sleep(3)
    #jsonized = map(lambda item: {'Name':item[0], 'Series':item[1]}, zip())
    print(MainHeaderArray)
    #time.sleep(2.5)
    #print(MainRowArray)
    #time.sleep(2.5)
    #print(zip())
    TsumName = []
    TsumSeries = []
    TsumBoxType = []
    TsumSkillDescription = []
    TsumFullCharge = []
    TsumMinScore = []
    TsumScoreIncreasePerLevel = []
    TsumMaxScore = []
    TsumFullUpgrade = []
    Iterations = 0
    MaxIterations = len(MainRowArray)
    while Iterations <= MaxIterations: #This will fire 1 time per Tsum
        print(Iterations)
        print(MainHeaderArray[Iterations][0]) #Holy this gives us Mickey ;
        print(MainHeaderArray[Iterations+1][0])
        print(MainHeaderArray[Iterations+2][0])
        print(MainHeaderArray[Iterations+3][0])
        TsumName.append(MainHeaderArray[Iterations][0])
        print(MainRowArray[Iterations][1])
        #At this point it will, of course, crash - that's because I only just realized I needed to append AND I just realized that everything
        #Isn't stored in a list as I thought, but rather a multi-dimensional array (as you can see below I didn't know this)
        TsumSeries[Iterations] = MainRowArray[Iterations+1] 
        TsumBoxType[Iterations] = MainRowArray[Iterations+2]
        TsumSkillDescription[Iterations] = MainRowArray[Iterations+3]
        TsumFullCharge[Iterations] = MainRowArray[Iterations+4]
        TsumMinScore[Iterations] = MainRowArray[Iterations+5]
        TsumScoreIncreasePerLevel[Iterations] = MainRowArray[Iterations+6]
        TsumMaxScore[Iterations] = MainRowArray[Iterations+7]
        TsumFullUpgrade[Iterations] = MainRowArray[Iterations+8]
        Iterations += 9
        print(Iterations)
    print("It's Over")
    time.sleep(3)
    print(TsumName)
    print(TsumSkillDescription)
```

Edit:
tl;dr my goal here is to be like
"For this Mission Card I need a Blue Tsum with high score potential, a Monster's Inc Tsum for a bunch of games, and a Male Tsum for a long chain.. what's the best Tsum given those?" and it'll be like "SULLY!" and automatically select it or at the very least give you a list of Tsums. Like "These ones match all of them, these ones match 2, and these match 1"

Edit 2:
Here's the command Line Output for the code above:
https://pastebin.com/vpRsX8ni

Edit 3: Alright, just got back for a short break. With some minor looking over I see what happened - my append code is saying "Append this list to the array" meaning I've got a list of lists for both the Header and Row arrays that I'm storing. So I can confirm (for myself at least) that these aren't nested lists per se but they are definitely 2 lists, each containing a single list at every entry. Definitely not a dictionary or anything "special case" at least. This should help me quickly find an answer now that I'm not throwing "multi-dimensional list" around my google searches or wondering why the list stuff isn't working (as it's expecting 1 value and gets a list instead).

Edit 4:
I need to simply add another list! But super nested.
It'll just store the categories that the Tsum has as a string.
so Array[10] = ArrayOfCategories[Tsum] (which contains every attribute in string form that the Tsum has)
So that'll be ie TsumArray[10] = ["Black", "White Gloves", "Mickey & Friends"]
And then I can just use the "Switch" that I've already made in order to check them. Possibly. Not feeling too well and haven't gotten that far yet.

Comment: Your question is to long and complexe. Please hold on and think about your problem. What is the quintessence of it? Then rewrite the answer, minimal and clearly. Also your code example should be smaller then. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the with open file as json_file , write/read (super easy).

Ultimately stored 3 json files. No big deal. Much easier than appending into one big file.